# Can a Jewish man be a sperm donor?

Tags: halacha, pregnancy-birth

What are the Halachik issues with donating sperm in a non-Jewish community?

Answer (score 9):

**No, a Jewish man cannot be a sperm donor.**

Based on tshuvos from Reb Moshe (Igrot Moshe, Even Ha'Ezer 1:71 & 4:32.5) we can say

1. Niuff byad is an issur which *only* married couples who undergo IVF can get around, but single guys in a clinic can't.
2. The assumption is that the sperm will go to a nonjew, so there is no kiyum of pru urvu to dissipate the issur of hotzaas zera livatala.
3. Since you can't guarantee that a Jewish woman won't end up impregnated with said sperm, you run into a problem of siblings from the same father possibly marrying each other, which is arayos and makes mamzeirim.

Comment: Do we need Kiyum Pru uRvu to dissipate it? Wouldn't we still allow for Bedika of a Kerut Shofkha to allow him to marry an Aylonit?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. I thought we don't ever allow bedikos for marriage. If you have something to share I'd be iinterested in seeing it.

Comment: I thought RMFs whole proof was from a Gemara in Yevamot about checking a Krut Shofkha to see if he could marry, and IVF is a Kol Shekein

Comment: @Double He mentions the theoretical case of using hot bread to test without niuf yes, but I don't think he believes that is actually muttar to do. The gemara itself was docheh that approach. Have you ever seen someone allowing that bedika?

Comment: #3 might be avoided if the donor is willing to reveal his identity to the parents?

Comment: #3 It should be noted that R' Moshe regarded a man artificially inseminating a married Jewish woman as not being adultery (many poskim agree with him.). However, other poskim (like the Satmar Rav) state that such is in fact adultery (or some hold its  close enough to be forbidden/avoided.)

Comment: This answer would be vastly improved if it would at the very least list the responsa of R'MF it refers to. Ideally, it should say how it got from them to its conclusions. Oh, and translating words into English would help, too.